# How to get two column of one row in one table using laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

in Laravel i can get value of two column in one table in this code

```
$customerName = Customer::where('id', '=', Input::get('customerID'))->first()->customer_name;
        $created_at = Customer::where('id', '=', Input::get('customerID'))->first()->created_at;
```

i want to know  that how to get this two value (customer_name and created_at) in one query

Answer (score 1):

I found this way in the doc:

```
Customer::where('id', '=', Input::get('customerID'))->lists('customer_name', 'created_at');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

Answer (score 1):

I use this code but not sure is it optimize or not

```
$customerID = Input::get('customerID');
$customer = Customer::findOrFail($customerID);
$customerName = $customer->customer_name;
$created_at = $customer->created_at;
```

Comment: This works fine and will only run one query. Not much to optimize here.